# Why I get a wrong time if a set the correct time zone in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save opening and closing hours of a branch as `time` in ruby ​​on rails, but it is saved with a difference of -6 hours when I need it to be -5 as it is the local time

In the other models I save date and time as `datetime` and the correct time is saved, 
but at the branch I only need time

In my application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Monterrey' // It has -5 difference
```

In my schema

```
  create_table "branches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.time "open_time"
    t.time "close_time"
  end

// In bookings work correctly

 create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "client_name"
    t.datetime "date"
  end
```

Example

If I save a Booking, has the correct time zone

```
> Booking.last.date
=> Sun, 12 Apr 2020 17:31:00 CDT -05:00
```

But if I save a branch, has a wrong time zone

```
> Branch.last.open_time
=> Fri, 31 Dec 1999 22:50:00 CST -06:00
```

Comment: Welcome! Naming the things, Caching and Timezones always difficult to deal with. Take a look at https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Comment: Good first question! Clear concise explanation of the problem, all relevant information is included.

Comment: There are _two_ local timezones in Monterrey. The standard timezone is CST (S=standard). But during the summer months, CDT is used (D=daylight, usually March–November). Therefore, the correct timezone for a summer date like 12 Apr is CDT whereas the correct timezone for a winter date like 31 Dec is CST. There's nothing "wrong" with your dates. Attempting to convert a winter date to a summer timezone (or vice versa) doesn't make much sense. It's like trying to make 8:00 p.m. (20:00) a "morning hour".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When showing a timestamp ruby will tell you both the name of the time zone (ie: CDT, CST), and the offset from UTC (ie: -05:00, -06:00). The two time zones you're seeing are:

- Central Daylight Time:

  ```
  > Booking.last.date
  => Sun, 12 Apr 2020 17:31:00 CDT -05:00
  ```
- Central Standard Time:

  ```
  > Branch.last.open_time
  => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 22:50:00 CST -06:00
  ```

Accounting for the daylight saving hours is the only difference between these time zones.

Geographically, both time zones represent the same area, where CST is used during the winter months, and CDT - during the summer months.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the CDT time when I run `Branch.last.open_time`

Comment: You either have to set `config.time_zone` to a time zone that doesn't track daylight saving hours (eg: `GMT-5`), or convert from one time zone to the other manually.

Comment: If you're asking this because you need to compare timestamps against one another within the application, then I would add `local_date` method to the model. The method would return `date` in local time zone, and  I would use it instead of `date` throughout the code… and if the application spans more then one time zone, I would seriously consider storing UTC times in the database. (At the very least, this would make it easier to compare timestamps in different time zones manually.)

Comment: @UrsaDK _"I would seriously consider storing UTC times in the database"_ – Rails already works that way. The database doesn't contain any timezone data.

Comment: @Stefan, yes that bit could be phrased better... In principle I agree with you, rails _should_ work that way and ActiveRecord _should_ store UTC timezone in the database. However, rails is very flexible and we don't know the value of the OP's `config.active_record.default_timezone`. So in this case, I feel it's better to err on the side of caution and give the OP an indication of common best practices. :)